# Getting an error of "Reference to non-static member function must be called"

Tags: c++, error-handling, static-members, pointer-to-member

I'm not able to understand what this error means, and what is causing it.

Here is my code, please help me to point out the mistake:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool sortbysec(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b)
    {
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }
    vector<int> topKFreAquent(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
    {
        unordered_map<int,int> m;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
        {
            m[nums[i]]++;
        }
        vector<pair<int,int>> v;
        for(auto it = m.begin();it != m.end();it++)
        {
            v.push_back(make_pair(it->first,it->second));
        }
        sort(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),sortbysec);
        v.resize(k);
        return v;
    }
};
```

I'm getting the error in the `sort()` call, the exact error is:

```
Line 19: Char 34: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        sort(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),sortbysec);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
```

I searched on StackOverflow and found an explanation for a different code, but I wasn't able to understand it properly.

Comment: Easiest fix is to make `sortbysec` a free function, although you could declare it `static` and tweak your call to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) expects a [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)-able function object, which can be a free function, a static class method, a functor, etc.  Something that can be called on as-is.

You are trying to pass in a non-static class method, which will not work since `sortbysec()` requires an object instance to call it, and hence has a hidden `this` parameter, which `std::sort()` has no way to pass in when calling the method.

The simplest fix to your error would be to just make `sortbysec()` be `static`, since it is not using any members of the `Solution` class, eg:

```
static bool sortbysec(const std::pair<int,int> &a, const std::pair<int,int> &b)
```

Otherwise, you can use [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to create a functor that ties the `Solution` object to the `sortbysec` method so it can be called without specifying the object, eg:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
    std::bind(&Solution::sortbysec, this, _1, _2)
);
```

Or, use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead to capture `this`, eg:

```
std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
    [this](const std::pair<int,int> &a, const std::pair<int,int> &b){
        return sortbysec(a, b);
    }
);
```

Which can be simplified a little in C++14 and later by using `auto`, eg:

```
std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
    [this](const auto &a, const auto &b){
        return sortbysec(a, b);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
sort(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),sortbysec);
```

This:

```
sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [this](const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2) {
    return this->sortbysec(p1, p2);
});
```

Or as the comment said, just declare your sort function static.

Also, your code still won't compile with this change because `v` is of type `vector<pair<int,int>>` and does not match your return type of `<vector<int>`

Comment: You don't need `this->` inside of the lambda, as long as `this` is captured then the compiler will look at it when resolving `sortbysec`. Also, in C++14 and later, you can simplify the lambda by using `auto` eg: `sort(..., [this](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) { return sortbysec(p1, p2); });`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - correct. I meant to add a comment that the explicit `this->` was for clarity.